# Python "variable not defined" error when it is

Tags: python, python-2.7

Below is the code I have been working on.  I am new to python and programing and have been trying to teach myself.

I get the following error.  But `messages` is defined so I don't understand.

```
[ec2-user@ip-172-31-46-164 ~]$ ./twitter_test16.sh
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "./twitter_test16.sh", line 53, in <module>
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)
NameError: name 'messages' is not defined
```

code:

```
import csv
import json
import oauth2 as oauth
import urllib
import sys
import requests
import time

CONSUMER_KEY = ""
CONSUMER_SECRET = ""
ACCESS_KEY = ""
ACCESS_SECRET = ""

class TwitterSearch:
    def __init__(self,
        ckey    = CONSUMER_KEY,
        csecret = CONSUMER_SECRET,
        akey    = ACCESS_KEY,
        asecret = ACCESS_SECRET,
        query   = 'https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.{mode}?{query}'
    ):
        consumer     = oauth.Consumer(key=ckey, secret=csecret)
        access_token = oauth.Token(key=akey, secret=asecret)
        self.client  = oauth.Client(consumer, access_token)
        self.query   = query

    def search(self, q, mode='json', **queryargs):
        queryargs['q'] = q
        query = urllib.urlencode(queryargs)
        return self.client.request(self.query.format(query=query, mode=mode))

def write_csv(fname, rows, header=None, append=False, **kwargs):
    filemode = 'ab' if append else 'wb'
    with open(fname, filemode) as outf:
        out_csv = csv.writer(outf, **kwargs)
        if header:
            out_csv.writerow(header)
        out_csv.writerows(rows)

def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)


    # I need to parse the content in js and turn it into a generator expression
    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
    #

write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)
```

I have "messages defined" so I dont know why I am getting an error telling me "messages" is not define.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Because the line `write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)` is **not** part of the `main()` function. The line has not been indented at all, so Python sees it as a separate line of code following the `main()` function, and executes it immediately when you run this script.

Indent that line to match the `messages` line, and don't forget to *call* `main()`:

```
def main():
    ts = TwitterSearch()
    response, data = ts.search('@gmail.com', result_type='recent')
    js = json.loads(data)

    messages = ([msg['created_at'], msg['txt'], msg['user']['id']] for msg in js.get('statuses', []))
    write_csv('twitter_gmail.csv', messages, append=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: Thank you so much.  That makes total sense to call main ().  As I have been teaching myself to code , this site has helped me so much.  Really appreciate it!